# How to enhance mongodb search

Tags: regex, mongodb

I have a dataset like this:

```
{
  _id: ObjectId("5b51a905c2ee6718204e945d"),
  post: "hello apple"
},
{
  _id: ObjectId("5b51a905c2ee6718204e945e"),
  post: "he is going to buy a cup of coffee"
}
```

Now I would like to create a search, for that, I wrote the query i.e.

```
db.Collection.find({
  post: { $regex: req.body.searchterm, $options: "i" }
}).then(data => {
  console.log(data);
})
.catch(error => {
  console.log(error)
});
```

This is working fine. Suppose I search "a" then it will return first and second object. But I want that result where a is individually written, not comes on between character.

I want only the second object return where a is written alone, but not comes on the first object because a is present on apple.

Any Suggestion on how I can enhance this. Any suggestion is really appreciated.

Comment: Word boundary. `\b`. Look it up.

Answer (score 0):

As Sergio suggested, use regex `\ba\b`. It will match only separate `a`

[Regex online demo](https://regex101.com/r/usYwq5/1)

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
var expression = new RegExp("(?=.*\\b" +req.body.searchterm + "\\b)")

db.Collection.find({
  post: { $regex: expression, $options: "i" }
}).then(data => {
  console.log(data);
})
.catch(error => {
  console.log(error)
});
```